# ¿Hacer que mi cadena[] se modifique según el id seleccionado en un DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Necesito que mi cadena de nombre "`cadena`" se modifique según el `Id` seleccionado que me devuelve el *DropDownList*.

> **Nota:** `cadena: [<%=CalAsignada %>]` es mi cadena a modificar.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control drop" ID="ddlPuestos" DataValueField="Valor" DataTextField="Texto" />
```

Mi cadena a modificar, está definida de la siguiente forma:
Está definida en mi aspx.cs de la siguiente forma

```
var empleadocom = _db.GraficaEmpleado(4, empleadoId);
if (empleadocom != null) { 
   foreach (DataRow row in empleadocom.Rows) { 
         cal_asi.Append(row["calificacion"]).Append(",");
   } 
   if (cal_asi.Length > 0){
      cal_asi = cal_asi.Remove(cal_asi.Length - 1, 1);
   } 
   CalAsignada = cal_asi.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende bien. que es data?

Comment: y esta definida en donde?

Comment: Agrega esa informacion a la pregunta. usa [edit] para modificar tu pregunta, y agrega toda la informacion relevante

Comment: No entender tu pregunta. 1ero. ¿`data:` es una propiedad de algún objeto de `JavaScript`? / 2do. ¿`CalAsignada` es una propiedad? / 3ero. ¿El código que agregaste de que evento de tu formulario es? / 4to. e **"importante"** ¿Quieres actualizar la información de lado cliente o servidor?. _Debes entender que no somos adivinos_

Comment: Tratando de adivinar.En **`cadena: [<%=CalAsignada %>]`**,  `cadena:` es una propiedad de objeto JS que al momento de renderizar de lado cliente sale en tu HTML como `cadena: [1,2,3,4]`, un ejemplo.Y quieres que al momento de seleccionar un nuevo valor de tu control `ddlPuestos` se actualice la propiedad o variable pública estática `CalAsignada` para que nuevamente considere un nuevo valor en el PostBack. Para ello, tu método `GraficaEmpleado` recibe como parámetro `puestoId` (en tu código está con valor **4**) y `empleadoId`.Además, que el código que pusiste pertenece a tu evento `Page_Load`.

Comment: Es correcto lo que describes, a excepción de que no está en mi evento page_load, lo tengo en mi metodo CargarRegistro()

Comment: Agregué una respuesta, pero me queda otra duda. ¿La variable `empleadoId` que viene hacer y de qué control se obtiene su valor?

Comment: empleadoId es la variable que nos dice de que empleado se mostrarán sus datos, en este caso su "calificación asignada"

Obtiene su valor de 

 var empleadocom = _db.GraficaEmpleado(4, empleadoId);

En donde "_db.GraficaEmpleado" contiene la consulta que trae los registros donde el Id del empleado sea igual al Id seleccionado


Voy a probar tu sugerencia, de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Para no estar refrescando la página y ver si agregaste un nuevo comentario, puedes usar @Davlio para que me notifique. Puedes revisar: [Responder en comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

En base a la adivinanza en los comentarios, debido a que los valores de tu propiedad `data` recibe como valor un arreglo desde el lado servidor a través de `cadena: [<%=CalAsignada %>]`, entonces sería necesario que tu control `ddlPuestos` tenga asignado:

- Propiedad `AutoPostBack="true"`: Para que realice el Postback de la página al momento de seleccionar un nuevo valor.
- Evento `OnSelectedIndexChanged`: Evento que se dispara al momento de seleccionar un nuevo valor.

---

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control drop" ID="ddlPuestos" DataValueField="Valor" DataTextField="Texto" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPuestos_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

**CS:**

```
protected void ddlPuestos_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int puestoId;
    int.TryParse(ddlPuestos.SelectedValue, out puestoId);

    var empleadocom = _db.GraficaEmpleado(puestoId, empleadoId);
    if (empleadocom != null) { 
       foreach (DataRow row in empleadocom.Rows) { 
             cal_asi.Append(row["calificacion"]).Append(",");
       } 
       if (cal_asi.Length > 0){
          cal_asi = cal_asi.Remove(cal_asi.Length - 1, 1);
       } 
       CalAsignada = cal_asi.ToString();
    }   
}
```